# IF statement that inserts text based on matching text

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a large table in excel that has column headings `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `ANSWER`

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` represent the multiple choice questions I have in the table.

I also have an `ANSWER` column that has the answers represented by the corresponding multiple choice heading letter mentioned above.

For example, under each column heading (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`), I have the possible answers, `Food`, `Car`, `House`, `School`.

In the example above, House (`C`) is the correct answer.  I would like to create an `IF` statement that matches the `Answer` cell, which has `C` in it with the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` column headings and if there's a match, then insert an `=` before the actual answer.  In this case, the result would be `=house`.  The rest of the answers should have the `~` inserted before the word, i.e., `~food`, `~car`, `~school`.

The final result should look like this: `~food`, `~car`, `=house`, `~school`.

Comment: Where should this result get written to?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code?

Comment: I want to replace the answers with the new prefixes, ~ or = or I can place the final corrected results in empty cells.

Comment: I'd like to do this with an if statement if possible as I am not familiar with coding

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve that securely is to duplicate the table in another sheet or in different columns.

Why is that?
Because you want to change the SOURCE of your statement. Excel would consider that a circular reference and couldn't resolve it.

There's a VBA code solution, that you can run ONLY ONCE. That would change the source data as well and you would lose your originals. Could be an action with no turning back.

So:

I suggest you create a new sheet, put the headers A, B, C and D.
So you would have two sheets: the `OriginalSheet` containing the answers and each option.
And the `ResultSheet`, containing the options formated as you want.

In the `ResultSheet`, use this formula:

```
= IF(OriginalSheet!$E2 = A$1; "="; "~") & OriginalSheet!A2
```

That is considering the first line containig the texts: A, B, C and D. So you must insert this formula in the `A2` cell of the `ResultSheet`.
You can click in the little black square in bottom right of the cell and drag this formula to all other cells. (The `$` simbols garantee the drag will be safe)